# How can I share data between two Windows 7 PCs on a LAN?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, home-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with network shares](https://superuser.com/questions/262262/problem-with-network-shares)

I have one desktop (Win 7 Pro 32-bit) and one laptop (Win 7 Home Premium 64-bit). I want to share data between the two PCs over my house's built-in LAN.

When I share the drives, I get the error

> Network Error: Windows cannot access \{Machine Name}

Also, I want to make sure that when any drives/folders/files are being shared, they cannot be accessed by any other person on the network. My Wi-Fi is password protected. Is it even possible for any other network to access my shared data?

How can I achieve this setup?

Comment: Do you have Client For Microsoft Networks installed on both computers?  Can you ping the computers by name?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way (computers are 32 and 64 per your notes):
* On each computer, in the documents folder create a new folder called share.  Share this folder through the property pages.
* On 32, go to start -> run and type in "\64\share" where 64 is the name of the 64-bit computer
* enter credentials for the 64 computer (username and password for the account that was logged into 64 when you created the share folder on it)
* you will now see the share folder and can copy files back and forth

There is no security issue unless you have an easy wifi password, are using WEP, and are also using easy usernames/passwords on the computers.

Comment: @echarnley: What if i need to share folders from directly computers drive? Is there something i missing while sharing between 2 PCs?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What exactly do you mean by sharing folders directly from computers drive?

Comment: i mean that insteading of keeping folders in share folders, if i need to share say the E Drive of 32 bit into 64 bit.

Comment: Okay is the E drive the root OS drive?  The answer will be different depending on that.

Comment: no it is the simple drive that contains data such as softwares, photos, music and all that stuff..

Comment: Then instead of creating a folder and sharing that, just right-click on the E drive and go to sharing.  Share it on the sharing tab AND on the security tab make sure the user account you are logged in as has full control.

Comment: Also - the user account on the XP computer needs to have a password. IF the 7 computer connects to the XP computer without a password, it will connect as the Guest account with no permissions.

Comment: @echarnley: I did the right click thing and select the sharing. I am login as a administrator and i am having a full control as far as security tab is concerned. Also both the OS are Windows 7

Comment: http://img199.imageshack.us/i/sharingerror.jpg/ 
See the error posted in the link.

Comment: Do you have passwords for the administrator accounts configured?

Comment: yes i do have passwords for both the computers

Comment: Okay try this: on computer 1 go to the command prompt and type: net use x: \\romilnagrani\h /USER:administrator.  Then enter the password when asked.  You should then be mapped to the H drive on romilnagrani

Comment: is the command something like "net use x: "???

Comment: net use x: \\romilnagrani\h /USER:administrator

Comment: USER in caps. And you should be prompted for the password.

Comment: am i missing something under Network Settings http://img820.imageshack.us/i/networksettingss.jpg/

Comment: No those look right.  Are you getting an error when you type in the net use command?

Comment: yes i do get..."The network path was not found".

Comment: use the IP address instead of the computername.  So type in \\192.168.1.102\h /USER:administrator (or whatever the computer romilnagrani IP address is)

Comment: The message came " the command completed successfully". no prompt for password???

Comment: okay now go to windows explorer and see if you have an X drive that maps to the H drive on romilnagrani

Comment: if they have the same admin password you might not be prompted

Comment: they dont have same password!!!

Comment: if it is working, please mark this question as answered!

Comment: its not working..! :-)

Comment: how is it not working?  Is there no X drive?  Is there an error message?

Comment: no there is no X drive...why does the X Drive came into picture??

Comment: net use X: \\192.168.1.102\h - that means you are creating a drive called X that is mapped to the network share \\192.168.1.102\H

Comment: I have to go to work now... good luck.  Perhaps you should read up on networking - good article here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/033c418b-1096-4df7-bfad-fd3d431f3cd5/